# Call function from external javascript file with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

so I'm seeing everyone else have no problems with this,

I included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vid.js"></script> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: stopCall();"/>
```

stopCall is defined in the vid.js file and it runs fine if I call it directly inside. There is no problem with the vid.js file btw, it's working completely fine. The problem is accessing any of vid.js's functions outside of the script itself. I can't seem to call it later in any form. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can we see the source code of `vid.js`?

Comment: The semicolon there is unnecessary as well.

Comment: @Feng Huo 1st remove the javascript: from onclick it's unnecessary. 2nd can we see the vid.js ?